# for Update Trigger - to insert values into a History Table

Tags: sql, triggers

This is what i have now:

```
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[trg_SourceHistory]    Script Date: 03/08/2011 14:38:08 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg_SourceHistory] 
ON [dbo].[tblSource]
for UPDATE
AS 
begin try
INSERT INTO tblHistorySource
select *, getdate()
from [DELETED]
end try
begin catch
SELECT
ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber,
ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity,
ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState,
ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure,
ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine,
ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
RAISERROR('Error in Source Hisotry Trigger' ,16,1)
ROLLBACK TRAN
END CATCH
```

but i keep getting the following error: Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

i was thinking that maybe it would be a good idea to write out all the fields in the trigger to make sure everythign matches up, but i can't seem to figure out the format to do so.

```
insert into tblHistorySource (value1, value2) values (value1, value2)
```

where do i put this???

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to list out all the columns

```
....
begin try
INSERT INTO tblHistorySource (value1, value2, somedatecolumn)  -- all the columns*
select value1, value2, getdate()   -- al
from [DELETED]
end try
....
```

* as many columns as exists in DELETED + column for getdate()

Comment: Thanks! i forgot parenthesis and couldn't get it to work before :)